# Как перевести группу файлов из window-1251 в UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8

Переводим наши проекты c window-1251 в UTF-8. Файлов много и надоедает их по одному импортировать.

Вопрос: Может кто то встречал программу для групповой обработки
например запустил прогу указал ей путь и она импортирует все файлы в папке?
ОС Windows 10

Comment: Какая операционная система? В Linux (или MSYS) можно воспользоваться связкой `find` + `iconv`.

Comment: Написать программку, которая будет рекурсивно обходить папки, открывать файл в одной кодировке и сохранять в другой. На Delphi, например.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какая операционная система? В Linux или MSYS (наборе утилит GNU, портированных под Windows) можно воспользоваться связкой `find` + `iconv`:

```
find -type f -exec "iconv -c -f WINDOWS-1251 -t UTF-8 -o {} {}"
```

Данная команда преобразует все файлы из кодировки Windows-1251 в UTF-8.

Однако стоит отметить, что в Java активно используется кодирование нелатинских символов в виде `\uXXXX`. Перекодировка в данном случае не поможет, если вообще хоть что-то изменит, так как латиница в нижней половине Windows-1251 имеет такое же битовое представление, как и в UTF-8 (нулевой старший бит и семь оставшихся битов для символа).

Comment: Windows 10, сейчас попробую

Comment: вроде и «родные» блобы собирают: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html